# bcrypt@3.0.3 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build` bcrypt 3.0.3

Tags: windows-10, command-line, bash, installation, node.js

Hello i tried everything to solve this issue, nothing worked.
im trying to install bcrypt and it drops this meesage

```
bcrypt@3.0.3 install: node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
```

the log of the issue (full log at https://github.com/kelektiv/node.bcrypt.js/issues/692) :

```
1198 warn rest-shop@1.0.0 No repository field. 
1199 verbose stack Error: bcrypt@3.0.3 install: `node-pre-gyp install
--fallback-to-build` 
1199 verbose stack Exit status 1 1199 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:301:16) 1199 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:182:13) 
1199 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14) 
1199 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13) 
1199 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:962:16) 
1199 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:251:5) 
1200 verbose pkgid bcrypt@3.0.3 
1201 verbose cwd C:\Users\user\Desktop\Programacion\Nodejs\node-rest-shop 
1202 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134 
1203 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "bcrypt" 
1204 verbose node v10.14.2 
1205 verbose npm  v6.4.1 1206 error code ELIFECYCLE 
1207 error errno 1 
1208 error bcrypt@3.0.3 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build` 
1208 error Exit status 1 1209 error Failed at the bcrypt@3.0.3 install script. 
1209 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above. 1210 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

package.json:

```
"dependencies": { "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3", "body-parser": "^1.18.3", "express": "^4.16.4", "mongoose": "^5.4.0", "morgan": "^1.9.1", "multer": "^1.4.1", "request": "^2.88.0" },
```

VERSIONS:

npm: 6.4.1

node: v10.14.2

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue today whilst trying to install bcrypt on Windows 10 desktop. Turns out that bcrypt support stable versions of node better check out the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt)

The solution for me was:

1. Upgrade node to a stable version: I manually downloaded and installed Windows installer from Node website.
2. Install the Windows build tools globally: `npm install --global --production windows-build-tools`
3. Finally `npm install bcrypt --save`

After this everything worked ok.

[Orginal Answer Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41899719/how-to-npm-install-bcrypt-on-windows-7)